# How to place the same path multiple times at different sizes/coordinates?

Tags: svg

I have a path I've created in Illustrator and saved as an SVG.

Now I want to programmatically place it at different sizes and coordinates on a large canvas.

Say I've got this image:

[image: original image]
<sub>(source: [omgtldr.com](http://omgtldr.com/img/original.png))</sub>

How would I reproduce that same image in different places and sizes in one SVG file, like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [omgtldr.com](http://omgtldr.com/img/multiple.png))</sub>

for example, one version shrunk by 20% at coordinates x,y; another enlarged by 30% at coordinates a,b and so on.

Please assume I'm going to be OK with the programming part, I'm comfortable working with XML files. It's the SVG parts I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the **[transform](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html)** attribute. You can move your paths with **translate** and resize them with **scale**.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use the `<use>` element (transformed) than to copy your path for each instance.